# JQuery Ajax is sending GET instead of POST. Request method 'GET' not supported

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

```
     $.ajax({
            url : 'saveeolref',
            type:"POST",
            cache:false,
            data:{
      "probId": probid,
      "rowid": rowid, 
        "ord": order},
            dataType: "json",
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response);                     
            },
             error: alert('fail')
        });

 <button type="button"  onclick="updateRef()">Submit</button>
```

- Ajax call

```
     $.ajax({
            url : 'saveeolref',
            type:"POST",
            cache:false,
            data:{
      "probId": probid,
      "rowid": rowid, 
        "ord": order},
            dataType: "json",
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response);                     
            },
             error: alert('fail')
        });
```

Comment: Javscript event:    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="updateRef()" > <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> Submit</button>

Comment: If you have more details, click the "edit" link and add it to the question.

Comment: Can you share the URL you are calling?

Comment: Why do you have `contentType: "application/json"`? jQuery doesn't send the object as JSON, it sends it as a URL-encoded string.

Comment: This code will definitely not send GET. That must be coming from something else. Maybe you forgot to call `event.preventDefault()`?

Comment: Why did you post the AJAX code twice?

Comment: Where do you want me to add 'event.preventDefault()' ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery above 1.9.0 try using the `method` property instead of `type`.

Also try to look at the initiator of the request in the debug panel of the "Network" browser to understand where in the code the GET request is sent from.

The reason why `dataType: "json"` was overriding the `type: "POST"` was because the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) specifies the following:

> "json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object. Cross-domain "json" requests that have a callback placeholder, e.g. ?callback=?, are performed using JSONP unless the request includes jsonp: false in its request options. The JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown. As of jQuery 1.9, an empty response is also rejected; the server should return a response of null or {} instead. (See json.org for more information on proper JSON formatting.)

That's to say that jQuery moved the request to a JSONP call instead of a POST one.

Comment: It worked :). After removing 'dataType: json'. But, i dont kow why. Thanks for responding!!